# QT application build in VS 2008 is not working in XP

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, qt, windows-7, windows-xp

Hello all i have created an application in VS 2008 using QT plugin & its is working fine in all the windows systems. 
But when I try to run the same application in XP it is showing error :: Procedure entry point xxx  could not  be located in xxx.dll .

How can I solve this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to install the VS 2008 runtime on the XP system.  You can do that several ways, including:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en
- an installer that comes with VS 2008 (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe`)
- incorporating the MSM package for the runtime in an MSI installer
- it might work to copy the DLLs from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT` into the same directory as your executable.

### Update:

Your program seems to be having a problem resolving a reference that's being looked for in msvcrt.dll - a system DLL that is not directly part of the VS 2008 runtime (msvcrt90.dll).  I tested some of the Qt demos in VS 2008 with the Qt addin, and I don't see them directly linking to msvcrt.dll (as I expect, the programs link to msvcr90.dll).

However, when I look at the programs using Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/), I do see that `msvcrt.dll` is pulled in - a result of linking to `advapi32.dll` (on my WinXP system, the link to `msvcrt.dll` is indirect though `netapi32.dll`).  The copy of `msvcrt.dll` on my WinXP SP3 system doesn't have an export for `wcscpy_s` while the one on Win7 does. But nothing using `msvcrt.dll` on WinXP attempts to import `wcscpy_s`, so there's no problem that it's not exported.

I suggest you use something like Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what's trying to pull in the missing `wcscpy_s` symbol from `msvcrt.dll`. I think that chances are good that you have a DLL that doesn't belong on WinXP or should be rebuilt to be 'XP-compatible'.

Comment: yes I tried this...i installed the VS with Qt plugin & created package....& installed in XP & Windows7 both it is working fine. BUt when I make the package in 7 & run in XP it is not. ??? WHy is this happening.

Comment: I'll need to research this some more - it looks like the Qt Plugin is not using the standard VS2008 CRT link library (that's why the error is referencing msvcrt.dll and not msvcr90.dll). If what I think is happening (they're using some sort of hack to link to the legacy msvcrt.dll), you'll probably have to choose to  not use the newer 'secure' runtime functions like `wcscpy_s()` since they're simply not in the legacy runtime DLL, or reconfigure the build to link to the VC9 libraries.

Comment: @Piotr: By 'legacy' I meant that the msvcrt.dll is not intended to support applications built with VS2005 and later (and probably VS2002/2003, but I'm not 100% sure about that at the moment).  Note what's said in your quote, "It is intended for future use only by system-level components".

Comment: @amrit_neo: see if my update in my answer helps with your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help...I have tried using Dependency walker but not able to understand how it works.

Comment: @amrit_neo: if you like you can use the "Save as..." menu item to save the Dependency Walker session (make sure "View/Full Paths" is enabled and that you're running it on the WinXP system with the problem. ).  Choose the "Text with Import/Export Lists" file type and compress it to a .zip file. Post the file somewhere that I can get it, and I'll take a look.